# Xpath multiple filter select

Tags: xml, wordpress, xpath, woocommerce, wpallimport

I am trying to achieve the following with Xpath but I can't get the selection to work.....

I have the following scenario:

Gender either male or female
Brandname: BrandA or BrandB or BrandC or BrandD

I want to select all MALE attributes with only BrandA, BrandB, and BrandC

If I use the following;

```
/node[gender[1] = "male"] (perfect selects only the male products)

/node[gender[1] = "male" and brand[1][contains(.,"BrandA")]](perfect Xpath selects only the male products with the BrandA)
```

So far so good but if I use the beneath standing is doesn't select anything....

```
/node[gender[1] = "male" and brand[1][contains(.,"BrandA")] and brand[1][contains(.,"BrandB")]]
```

Any suggestions? what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you show your sample xml excerpt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `or` between brand names to select any of them and `and` with gender

```
/node[gender[1] = "male" and 
      (brand[1][contains(.,"BrandA")] or brand[1][contains(.,"BrandB")])]
```

when you combine all with `and` Xpath finds nothing because brand[1], probably, can contain BrandA and BrandB at the same time

Comment: Hi that is what i tried but the following 
 /node[gender[1] = "male" and 
      (brand[1][contains(.,"BrandA")] or brand[1][contains(.,"BrandB")]]

 selects al products of the Gender Male. Even products with BrandC. It should filter out BrandC but that is not happening....

Comment: videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Croot%3E%3Cnode%3E%3Cgender%3Emale%3C%2Fgender%3E%3Cbrand%3EBrandA%3C%2Fbrand%3E%3C%2Fnode%3E%3Cnode%3E%3Cgender%3Efemale%3C%2Fgender%3E%3Cbrand%3EBrandA%3C%2Fbrand%3E%3C%2Fnode%3E%3Cnode%3E%3Cgender%3Emale%3C%2Fgender%3E%3Cbrand%3EBrandC%3C%2Fbrand%3E%3C%2Fnode%3E%3C%2Froot%3E%0A&=&extract=%2F%2Fnode%5Bgender%5B1%5D%20%3D%20%22male%22%20and%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(brand%5B1%5D%5Bcontains(.%2C%22BrandA%22)%5D%20or%20brand%5B1%5D%5Bcontains(.%2C%22BrandB%22)%5D)%5D%0A%0A%0A&=%2F&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=xml&extract-kind=xpath2

Comment: Hi Splash... I am not sure what you send? The code looks at it his been messed up :).... Can you resend your answer thanks!

Comment: That is link to xpath tester